# Recurring payments and IPN

Tags: php, paypal

Where i can set `notify_url option for reccuring payments? I oficial documentation written, that notify_url is ignored in`SetExpressCheckout or GetExpressCheckoutDetails`. I want to receive payment status.

Answer (score 1):

The same notation that you're referring to indicates that the notify_url is set via the DoExpressCheckout call. When creating the recurring payments profile via Express Checkout, simply include PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call and you will be notified there of new payments made and their status.